# Email mistakenly marked as spam

Tags: email, spam-prevention

I have my own email server and I've recently noticed that many of the emails I sent ended up in the recipients' spam folder. I have verified the IP of my mail server and it's not in any blacklist. What could be causing this? Could it be that my IP doesn't have a long history? How can I fix this?

Comment: Long history?  Is the IP a static address?

Comment: Don't send spam, maybe? At last, it's recipient's side solution, you have to ask other side, not blindly find non-existent answer

Comment: Ask one of the recipients to forward you a mail that went to Spam. Then check the mail headers for possible information why it went to Spam.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the [MXToolBox SuperTool](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx):

- To check if your IP is on any blacklist, enter the command:

  ```
  blacklist:IP
  ```
- To check if your IP has a [reverse DNS record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup), enter the command:

  ```
  ptr:IP
  ```
- To check if your IP has a [forward-confirmed reverse DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS), enter the command:

  ```
  a:hostname
  ```

  where hostname if the result of the second check. It should return your IP.

Other things you can try to pass common spam filters (like Google's):

- Set up a [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) record.
- Sign your emails with the [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) method.
- Request your IP to be whitelisted (e. g., on [dnswl.org](http://dnswl.org/request.pl)).

Comment: and after all get content-analyzer on recipient side, which consider text as spam anyway