# outgoing email blocked as spam

Tags: router, microsoft-outlook

I have MS Office 2013 on Windows 10 and 2 days ago, my email suddenly started to block my outgoing emails. I get a message

> 550 5.7.1 Spam detected by content scanner.  Message rejected.

I believe it has to do with my router (AC 87U) because I put the cable straight to the modem, bypassing the router, and it worked fine.

Comment: Have you tried to disable the content scanner (AiProtection) on the AC87U?

Comment: Might be related: [Link01](https://superuser.com/q/830060/485660), [Link02](https://superuser.com/q/396650/485660)

Comment: I'm doubting if you have any third-party ad-in related. you can try open outlook in safe mode. Exit Outlook, press Win key + R to open the Run command, type outlook.exe /safe and then press Enter.

Comment: Do you have optonline mail? if so, it's their scanners. I'm still trying to contact them to find out how to release it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/899232)